# How can the following demonstration be done?

Tags: complex-analysis

Please explain in detail, thank you

1.- Using the Cartesian and polar representations, show that every complex number of the form $z = x + iy$ can be represented in a matrix form as follows:

$ z=r\begin{pmatrix}  \cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta) \\   \sin(\theta)& \cos(\theta)  \end{pmatrix} $

and that with this representation the multiplication of complex numbers is precisely matrix multiplication.

2.-Using the above representation, show that if $z$ and $c$ are complex numbers, and $c$ has norm $1$, then the multiplication $cz$ is a complex number with the same norm as $z$, whose argument is the sum of the arguments of $z$ and $c$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Users of this site will expect you to provide some context and effort to your question, so as to guanrantee that they are helping you understand something rather than do your homework for you. Please include your your thought around the problem. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cartesian representation of a complex number $z$ is of the form $x+iy,$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. A polar representation of a complex number $z$ is of the form $re^{i\theta},$ where $r$ is a non-negative real number and $\theta$ is real.

To see how a matrix representation might work, we'll want to actually play with the given form and see how it is similar to what we're used to.

Let's consider two matrices of this form, say $z=r\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\theta&-\sin\theta \\   \sin\theta& \cos\theta  \end{pmatrix}$ and $w=R\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\phi&-\sin\phi \\   \sin\phi& \cos\phi  \end{pmatrix}.$

Then based on a little knowledge of matrix multiplication and trigonometric identities, we see that $$zw=rR\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\theta&-\sin\theta \\   \sin\theta & \cos\theta  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\phi&-\sin\phi \\   \sin\phi& \cos\phi  \end{pmatrix}\\zw=rR\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\theta\cos\phi-\sin\theta\sin\phi&-\cos\theta\sin\phi-\sin\theta\cos\phi \\   \sin\theta\cos\phi+\cos\theta\sin\phi & -\sin\theta\sin\phi+\cos\theta\cos\phi  \end{pmatrix}\\zw=rR\begin{pmatrix}  \cos(\theta+\phi)&-\sin(\theta+\phi)\\\sin(\theta+\phi) & \cos(\theta+\phi)  \end{pmatrix}.$$

On the other hand, if $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w=Re^{i\phi},$ then $$zw=rRe^{i(\theta+\phi)},$$ so this matrix representation acts in the same way that we're used to polar form working.

But what about an analog to Cartesian form? Well, that's doable, too. Remember that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta,$ which allows us to translate from the polar form to $r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta,$ then we rename $r\cos\theta=x$ and $r\sin\theta=y.$ This certainly suggests that we might accomplish something similar with the matrix form by writing $$z=r\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\theta&0 \\   0& \cos\theta  \end{pmatrix}+r\begin{pmatrix}  0&-\sin\theta \\   \sin\theta& 0  \end{pmatrix},$$ or equivalently, $$z=\begin{pmatrix}  r\cos\theta&0 \\   0& r\cos\theta  \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}  0&-r\sin\theta \\   r\sin\theta& 0  \end{pmatrix}.$$ Hence, our substitution would yield $$z=\begin{pmatrix}  x&0 \\   0& x  \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}  0&-y \\   y& 0  \end{pmatrix},$$ or equivalently, $$z=x\begin{pmatrix}  1&0 \\   0& 1  \end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}  0&-1 \\   1& 0  \end{pmatrix},$$ but does this actually behave the way we want? I'll leave it to you to verify that multiplication here acts just like multiplication of complex numbers in Cartesian form.

The argument I demonstrated above shows what you need for the second part. Do you see why?